# How can i test react components based on jQuery-UI?

Tags: jquery, testing, reactjs, jestjs

I need to test functionality of slider component in react based on jQuery-UI slider.

i tried using Jest and unMock jQuery but i'm getting an outerWidth undefined error from jQuery.

no luck so far googling this :)

Comment: is it because you're not actually rendering the slider into a real document, therefore the dimensions (like outerWidth) aren't available?

Comment: maybe, but i want to keep using Jest

Comment: You still can, just don't use TestUtils.renderIntoDocument. Manually render the component into a real page. renderIntoDocument doesn't actually do what it says, it renders into an isolated div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this, looks like the solution
http://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/102274727496/to-testutil-or-not-to-testutil